# HTML5 Microdata/Schema.org "Thing>Person" implementation

Tags: html, seo, microdata

The old way of using Microdata to semantically declare an `itemprop="image"` for `itemtype=".../Person"` was as follows:

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Andy Runie</h1>
    <p>
        <img itemprop="photo" src="http://www.example.com/photo.jpg">
    </p>
</section>
```

Easy enough.

Evidently (per ***[the documentation](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146646)***) the previous approach is being deprecated and the "new" schema to use in HTML5 Microdata is [Schema.org](http://schema.org/).

This was taken from ***[the documentation](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146646)***
[image]

The [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) documentation shows that "Thing" is the parent for "Person"

and

`itemprop="image"` is now under "Thing." Whereas before `itemprop="photo"` was under "Person."

According to the ***[documentation](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html)*** (2a. [schema.org](http://schema.org/) types and properties) we find that ***Person*** inherits from ***Thing***...

**Question:**
Using this new standard, can I simply use the following to appropriately show in my HTML that an '`is`itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"`?

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Andy Runie</h1>
    <p>
        <img itemprop="image" src="http://www.example.com/photo.jpg">
    </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

If you navigate to http://schema.org/Person you can use all mentioned properties to describe a person, that includes all properties from [Thing](http://schema.org/Thing) like image, name, description and url.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.
Well, actually there is an example below the schema.org/Person page that answers your question.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="name">Jane Doe</span>
  <img src="janedoe.jpg" itemprop="image" />
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

and here you can find another example with Schema.org this time using itemprop="jobtitle" and itemprop="url" : [example](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_attributes/link/html5_link_itemprop_attribute.php)